# How to select multiple values from select in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

My question is how to select multiple values in Angular. Approach I tried till now is :

**Template:**

```
<select multiple class="form-control" (click)="addDetails(t.value)" #t>
                    <option selected disabled>Select all applicable</option>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                </select>
```

Then I am tapping all values in my class. However this does not look like a good approach to me. I was wondering how can I leverage Angular's data mapping here.

**Component:**

```
 addDetails(value){
    this.selectedValues = this.selectedValues.concat(',');
  }
```

*PS: I am removing last comma before using. Also I do not want to use any extra plugins since I do not have luxury to install here :(.*

Please help.

Comment: just use `[(ngModel)]`, angular will automatically map the `select multiple` to an array.  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/SelectMultipleControlValueAccessor-directive.html

Comment: It is not working. I tried following : <select multiple class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="test.value">
                    <option selected disabled>Select all applicable</option>
                    <option [ngValue]="A">A</option>
                    <option [ngValue]="C">C</option>
                    <option [ngValue]="B">B</option>
                </select>

Comment: Never mind. I use the value (plain instead of ngValue) and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `md-select` from angular-material2 that has a `multiple` property, and easily binds via `ngModel`. Plunker
[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/8HuIDnlFHTHe56HC4jby?p=preview).

I was also able to use your code and bind the value with `ngModel`. In the following [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/rzP1J0nPxh8yZ3DwfE38?p=preview), you can select A, B, C (Hold Shift + Click available options) and see all of them getting added to `selectedValue`